# Advanced IP Scanner - inactive hosts

Tags: networking, lan

I use Advanced IP Scanner.

When I scan my network at my office, then I see only 3 active hosts (my computer, my router, and my coworker computer).

I also see 10 inactive hosts.
I thought that inactive means that they are not currently available on the LAN.

So I wondering about:

Why are the inactive hosts listed?

How they can be found?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I believe inactive hosts are hosts that have been found in previous scans.

Comment: Do you mean that this software somehow store it in some kind of container and after reboot he compares Active and all known hosts ?

Comment: Yes, the app has a cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the cache in V2.4 and beyond to see only active data.

Options, Misc and Clear Data.

[image]

Comment: This option is exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks